# Uploading usage files larger than approx 4MB gives an Internal Server Error (500)

Tags: recommendation-engine, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to upload usage files to a Microsoft Cognitive Services Recommendations model. The catalog and usage files come from the [code sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Recommendations-API-Basic-d3e5f820#content) provided by the api team. The catalog file uploads without problems.

**modelId**: *6db7e661-e942-4e9a-9bd0-c54a29cd96c5*

When I upload usage files larger than approx 4MB then I receive a response like this:

```
{ "statusCode": 500, "message": "Internal server error", "activityId": "fd910356-9cb2-474f-93b2-ce79004e11b6" }
```

I have tried the following methods and in each case the results were equivalent. If the file was larger than approx 4MB then the upload fails.

- [API endpoint](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/Recommendations.V4.0/operations/56f316efeda5650db055a3e2/console) exposed in the docs
- sample C# [RecommendationsSample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Recommendations-API-Basic-d3e5f820) console app
- custom built nodeJS server using the [unirest](http://unirest.io/nodejs.html) package

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the http client is timing out on while upload of the file is still progress. Can you increase the timeout of httpclient and retry?

Comment: I will give the timeout suggestion a go but would a client-side timeout return a server fault `statusCode: 500`? My assumption was that this return code was proof that the server had tripped up but maybe the server is failing because the client is timing out?